# Fatal error with defined() in PHP

Tags: php, constants, fatal-error

if I check for `defined('SomeClass::CONSTANT')` and SomeClass does not exist I get a fatal error. Shoudn't defined() return false instead?

Comment: fatal error: class SomeClass not found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this can be the alternative solution..

```
if (class_exists('class_name')) {
     if(defined('class_name::CONSTANT')){
          // your logic   
     }
}
```

Comment: It's the solution for PHP < 5.3... No error in PHP 5.3/5.4. Yeah it's really broken by design.